# Outlook 2007 ItemAdd event firing without being sent an object, argument is empty

Tags: vba, outlook

I have the following code in `ThisOutlookSession`. It runs when an item is added to my sent email folder. It fires like it's supposed to but it keeps telling me that 'the argument isn't optional'. I've looked at a lot of examples and used it to build this one. I can't figure out what I am doing wrong. Looks like I am doing everything by the book but still my `item` argument in `myItems_ItemAdd` still comes up empty.

```
Private WithEvents myItems As Outlook.Items
Private Sub Application_Startup()
  Set myItems = Outlook.Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderSentMail).Items
End Sub
Private Sub myItems_ItemAdd(ByVal Item As Object)
  Dim olNS As Outlook.NameSpace
  On Error GoTo ErrorHandler
  Dim Msg As Outlook.MailItem

  If TypeName(Item) = "MailItem" Then
    Set Msg = Item
    If InStr(Msg.Body, "[W]") > 0 Then
        FlagWaitingForAnswerAndMove (Msg)
    End If

  End If
ProgramExit:
  Exit Sub
ErrorHandler:
  MsgBox Err.Number & " - " & Err.Description
  Resume ProgramExit
End Sub
```

Comment: Comment out On Error GoTo ErrorHandler and indicate the line that generates the error. Do not use error handlers until there are no errors to handle.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to debug the code? Do you get any errors?

Most probably the following condition returns false and you consider it as empty:

```
If TypeName(Item) = "MailItem" Then
```

Is that the case?

Try to remove the mentioned condition. Does it help?